# Swift how to set UIView's height constraint based on it's content

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a UIView in my swift code

```
let profile_inf_wrapper: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    profile_inf_wrapper.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant:64).isActive = true
    profile_inf_wrapper.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    profile_inf_wrapper.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    profile_inf_wrapper.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:  view.frame.height/4).isActive = true

    backgroundImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profile_inf_wrapper.topAnchor).isActive = true
    backgroundImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profile_inf_wrapper.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    backgroundImageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profile_inf_wrapper.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    backgroundImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profile_inf_wrapper.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    profileImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profile_inf_wrapper.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImage.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant:25).isActive = true
    profileImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 110).isActive  = true
    profileImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 110).isActive = true

    usernameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profile_inf_wrapper.topAnchor, constant:40).isActive = true
    usernameLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImage.rightAnchor, constant:20).isActive = true

    countryIcon.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: usernameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant:10).isActive = true
    countryIcon.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImage.rightAnchor, constant:20).isActive = true
    countryIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    countryIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25 ).isActive = true

    countryName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: usernameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant:5).isActive = true
    countryName.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: countryIcon.rightAnchor, constant:10).isActive = true
    countryName.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
```

All these elements are the subviews of `profile_inf_wrapper`.Sometimes `view.frame.height/4` is too small and i want to be able to resize the UIView based on it's content

Comment: it is very easy just make your UIview(which you have to resize) view.bottom.equalTo(lastViewofView.bottom)

Comment: Kind suggestion: Add a space behind `,`s.

Comment: @JaydeepVyas but last one has no `bottomAnchor`

Comment: @meaning-matters thanks for the suggestion

Comment: in above code which is your lastview

Comment: @JaydeepVyas `countryName`

Comment: make bottom constraint for mainview and then bottomConstraint.constant = countryName.frame.origin.y + countryName.frame.size.height
view.layoutSubviews()

Comment: What is mainview and where should i put it's bottom constraints?

Comment: mainView is your view you want to resize and from storyboard you can give contraint and drag to class you can also get outlet and then you can edit it

Comment: @JaydeepVyas `bottomAnchor` has no member constant and i can't give it `constraint(equalToConstant`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150456/discussion-between-jaydeep-vyas-and-sakoaskoaso).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setting the height of uiview dynamically you have to add height/bottom constraint to the view in your problem it might be

```
profile_inf_wrapper.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.height/4+countryName.frame.size.height).isActive = true
```

you also need the view size to fit to get actual updated size 
like

```
countryName.sizeToFit()
```

And then update layout if needed to get all affect

Answer (score 1):

There's a property in `UIView` called `intrinsicContentSize`. It returns the smallest size that the view would need show all of it's content.

While the default implementation is not very useful because a `UIView` doesn't have any content on it's own, all of the default subclasses implement it.

A `UILabel` will return a size that fits the text perfectly, and a `UIButton` will return a size that fits it's contents plus whatever spacing you've added. You get the gist of it.

You can take advantage of this property by only constraining either `width` or `height` of a view, not both. If you constrain the `width` of a `UILabel` and add more text, it will grow vertically.

Finally, when you add subviews to a `UIView`, and you add constraints to both margins of an axis (`top and bottom` or `left and right`), as long as there's a "chain" of constraints and views, and the view doesn't have any constraints on the size, it will expand to fit.

For example, if you have a view with a label and a button, vertically arranged, if the label is constrained to the top, then constrained to the button, and the button is constrained to the bottom, as long as the container view doesn't have a `height` constraint, it will expand to fit the two views plus the margins perfectly.

Your goal should always be to use the least amount of constraints to express your design, without removing useful constraints. Make sure you take advantage of the `intrinsicContentSize`.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to do is make a reference to the height constraint of profile_inf_wrapper.

```
var profile_inf_wrapper_height_constraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
```

I don't know the details of your content, but when the view needs resized, you can check that with a conditional in your viewController,

```
if contentRequiresResizing {
    profile_inf_wrapper_height_constraint.constant = view.frame.width/3
else {
    profile_inf_wrapper_height_constraint.constant = view.frame.width/4
}
```

By referencing constraints, it allows you to support dynamic UI changes easily.

As a side note, I would recommend renaming your UIView variable name so that the reference constraint isn't so long. The Swift 3 API guidelines also support lowerCamelCase, as opposed to underscore naming.